# How to use commandArgs to select dataframe from results

Tags: r

I've created a script that queries a database like so:

```
args <- commandArgs(True)
query <- paste('Select ', args[2], ' from ', args[1], ';')
results <- influxdb_query('localhost', '999', 'admin', 'password', 'db', query)
```

The script has the following usage:

```
>>> Rscript <program_name.R> <table_name> <column_name>
```

When I get ***results***, I can't use the ***table_name*** args[1] parameter to access the returned dataframe.  For example, I'd like to do the following:

```
>>> Rscript program.R user_calls values
```

and then access the results with the following:

```
results$args[1]
```

and also have the ability to access a column like so:

```
results$args[1]$args[2]
```

As of now, the previous method returns errors.  I'm forced to explicitly name the dataframe like so:

```
results$user_calls
```

which makes the program much less malleable.

So is there any way to use command line arguments to select the resulting dataframe and/or columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need

```
results[[args[1]]]
```

and

```
results[[args[1]]][[args[2]]]
```

i.e., use `[[` instead of `$`. See `?Extract` for details.

Comment: Thank you very much!  That worked. I tried something like that earlier, but apparently I needed another bracket.